# JSON response not deserialising in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm coding in C# using Xamarin Forms and simply trying to pull out some data from a JSON response.

I have a JSON response I'm trying to deserialise but I can't seem to pull out the nested variables (billing & shipping)

Here's the JSON response:

```
[{
    "id": xxxx,
    "date_created": "2020-09-04T11:01:46",
    "date_created_gmt": "2020-09-04T01:01:46",
    "date_modified": "2020-09-04T11:06:42",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2020-09-04T01:06:42",
    "email": "xxxx",
    "first_name": "xxx",
    "last_name": "xxx",
    "role": "customer",
    "username": "xxxxx",
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "xxx",
        "last_name": "xxx",
        "company": "xxx xxx",
        "address_1": "XXX",
        "address_2": "XXXX",
        "city": "XXX",
        "postcode": "XXX",
        "country": "XXX",
        "state": "XXX",
        "email": "XXXX",
        "phone": "xxxx"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "xxx",
        "last_name": "xx",
        "company": "xxx",
        "address_1": "xxx",
        "address_2": "xxxx",
        "city": "xxx",
        "postcode": "xxx",
        "country": "xx",
        "state": "xxx"
    },
    "is_paying_customer": false,
```

Here's my code:

```
root2 myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root2>(response_package);
Console.WriteLine("Shipping First Name: " + myDeserializedClass.MyArray[0].billing.first_name);
```

Here's my classes (generated from json2csharp)

```
public class Billing
        {
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string company { get; set; }
            public string address_1 { get; set; }
            public string address_2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string postcode { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone { get; set; }
        }

        public class Shipping
        {
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string company { get; set; }
            public string address_1 { get; set; }
            public string address_2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string postcode { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyArray
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
            public DateTime date_created_gmt { get; set; }
            public DateTime date_modified { get; set; }
            public DateTime date_modified_gmt { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public string username { get; set; }
            public Billing billing { get; set; }
            public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
            public bool is_paying_customer { get; set; }
            public string avatar_url { get; set; }
            public List<MetaData> meta_data { get; set; }
            public Links _links { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root2
        {
            public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; }

        }
```

The reason why I'm using Root2 is because the other Root is being used (no pun intended)

Comment: is that a valid json?

Comment: @Umang -- it's not, but it's not necessary to have the complete JSON to see what isn't quite right.

Comment: @Andy I think the author should still provide valid json.

Comment: @Umang -- ok, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyArray[]>(response_package);
Console.WriteLine("Shipping First Name: " + lst[0].billing.first_name);
```

There is nothing in that JSON that has this signature:

```
{
    MyArray = [{ ... },{ ... }]
}
```

It has this signature:

```
[{ ... },{ ... }]
```

Since the base object is an array, you have to deserialize to an array type. `List<MyArray>` would work here as well, for example:

```
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(response_package);
```